# QGIS does not open (installation problem?)

Tags: qgis, installation

I downloaded QGIS 1.8.0 (Windows) and installed the software. Installation was completed succesfully. However, I cannot open the software. When I start the QGIS, I receive an error message "qgis.exe has stopped working".

Tim

Comment: Might this is the bug..try to remove 3rd party plugin and then try..check this link http://hub.qgis.org/issues/6758

Comment: Which installer did you use? We have standalone and OSGeo4W. You might try the other one.

Comment: Are you installing it on a 64-bit machine/OS? Check to see if there's a 64-bit installer available.

Comment: Did you previously have an earlier version of QGIS installed?

Comment: Which version of Windows is the machina?